# While loops don't work

Tags: python, menu, pygame

My problem is the menu, It shows "Press space to play!"
But when i press it, it doesn't work!
I think its a problem with the while loops
I can't display code correctly so here's a link to my code
https://github.com/Donutoftime44/nheon-shooter
I tried putting if statements in my code like

```
while not done:
  if menu:
    ...
  elif not menu:
    ...
```

But it still does'nt work!
Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't display code correctly, but you have correctly-formatted code right in your post?

Comment: There is way too much code in your link. Strip it down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), or no one is going to read through all of it to help you.

Comment: There are many examples in the world that while loops do work.  Might I suggest a title that is more descriptive to your actual problem?  That way people who know how to help are more likely to find your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
   while menu:
      for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
          pg.quit()
          sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYUP:
          if event.key == K_SPACE:
            print "playing"
            done = True
```

Because you never change menu the loop never breaks, I believe you may want to add `menu = False` in `if event.key == K_SPACE:`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about this portion of the code:

```
while menu:
  for event in pg.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
      pg.quit()
      sys.exit()
    if event.type == KEYUP:
      if event.key == K_SPACE:
        print "playing"
        done = True
  windowdisplay.fill(colors["gray"])
  windowdisplay.blit(label, ((maxx / 2) - 100, maxy - 25))
  pg.display.update()
```

It seems like you want to end the loop when the user presses space. In which case, you need:

```
if event.key == K_SPACE:
    menu = False
```

Setting `done` equal to `True` does nothing, since `done` doesn't appear anywhere else in your code.